# How to use environment vars in GitHub actions?

Tags: github-actions

```
env:
  APP_PATH: ${{ github.workspace }}/MyApp/Build/Applications/MyApp.app

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
      - name: Upload app
        uses: svenstaro/upload-release-action@v2
        with:
          file: ${APP_PATH}
```

This fails with:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '${APP_PATH}'
```

The [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables) say to use, e.g. `$DAY_OF_WEEK`, but it doesn't work. I've tried `$APP_PATH`, `${APP_PATH}`, and `${{APP_PATH}}`.

Comment: You probably might want to prefix your variable with `env.`, personally I use secrets which you use this way `${{ secrets.Variable }}` and you can set them from 'settings > secrets > actions'

Comment: @Amineze, That worked, thank you! I guess I can't read; it is mentioned in the docs, further down.

Comment: Ha, sure!
Like...who loves to read docs :p